# Is there any way to emulate meta programming in C++?

Tags: python, c++, metaprogramming

Is there any way to emulate meta programming in C++ ? ( c++ not c++11 standard)
For Python on stack suggests ([Generate specific names proeprties using metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221981/generate-specific-names-proeprties-using-metaclass)) me to create like and it works

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(FooMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        for n in range(100):
           setattr(cls, 'NUMBER_%s'%n, n)

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
```

But I also need same class in C++, class with n static const int NUMBER_some_number fields.
How to create this without hardcoding ?

Comment: Check out template metaprogramming.

Comment: What is your definition of metaprogramming exactly ?

Comment: Why do you need such a class? Would `static int NUMBER(int n) constexpr  { return n; }` do the trick? Why is it important to write `NUMBER_42` and not `NUMBER(42)`?

Comment: The problem is there is no reflection/introspection in C++. Without that, even if you could figure out a template metaprogram that would do what you want, you'd have no way to access it without hard-coding the access, at which point you might as well have just written it that way in the first place.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have already code with NUMBER_something and I want to avoid to replace on all places and break code of other people.

Comment: Write a program that generates a file containing `enum {NUMBER_0 = 0, NUMBER_1 = 1, ..., NUMBER_100 = 100}`. Include this file as necessary (hint: `#include` directive may appear anywhere in the source file, e.g. within the class definition).

Answer (score 3):

In Python naming the first few hundred integers can have a slight performance advantage, since a typical implementation only caches a few hundred integers, and there's still a look-up for them.

In C++ integers are not dynamic objects so there is no problem and no advantage.

In C++ meta programming is now typically done by using the template mechanism. Before that was introduced one used macros to generate code. However, since the Python problem that you're addressing doesn't exist in C++, there's no point.

Answer (score 1):

As "Cheers and hth. - Alf" pointed out there is no performance gain when you do the same thing in c++.
Moreover it would be *really* absolutely bad style that should be avoided at all costs.
It is like not programming in c++ at all.

If for some reason you still cannot avoid doing that you could use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
    static const int NUMBER_ ## n = n;

// NOTE the valid range you can iterate over has to be a subset of [0, BOOST_PP_LIMIT_ITERATION]
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (0, 99)

class Bar
{
    public:
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
};
```

You can see the expanded result when calling for example

```
g++ -E file.h
```

where file.h is the file you put your code in.

One note though. Things like Boost.Preprocessor should not be overused as that again would be bad style
Macros can be quite useful, but I try to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: Yes they can save a lot of time.though I have the feeling that it makes people lazy as well. Instead of thinking of a better design just "generate some code".